# can i use aggregation function (LAST) in mysql?

Tags: mysql

can i use  aggregation function (LAST)  in mysql??
if yes then why give me error for following query::

```
SELECT `user_id`,last(`value`)
FROM `My_TABLE`
group by `user_id`
```

**ERROR**:: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(`value`) FROM `My_TABLE` group by `user_id`' at line 1

**EDIT**:: I got answer "last" is not used in MySql. then How to perform it in MySql??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, There is nothing called LAST in mysql

See the list of [aggregated function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

**EDIT**

You can perform the same something like this

```
select f.user_id, f.value
from (
   select  MAX(value) as maxval
   from my_table group by user_id
) as x inner join my_table as f on f.value = x.maxval
```

Comment: CAUTION: If there are two rows that match `f.value = x.maxval`, for a given `user_id`, then the result will contain BOTH rows.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this -

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1
  JOIN (SELECT depno, MAX(id) max_id FROM table1 GROUP BY depno) t2
    ON t1.depno = t2.depno AND t1.id = t2.max_id
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no "last" function defined in MySQL. Are you just trying to get the last (newest) record?

If so:

```
SELECT `user_id`, `value`
FROM `My_TABLE`
ORDER BY `user_id` DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

or

```
SELECT `user_id`, `value`
FROM `My_TABLE`
WHERE `user_id` = (SELECT MAX(`user_id`));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `last_value` in MySQL instead

```
CREATE TABLE comments (
  user_id VARCHAR(50),
  value VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO comments 
  (user_id, value)
VALUES
  ('Tim', 'comment1'),
  ('Tim', 'comment2'),
   ('Tim', 'comment3'),
  ('Tim', 'comment4'),
    ('Mark', 'comment1'),
  ('Mark', 'comment2'),
   ('Mark', 'comment3'),
  ('Mark', 'comment4');

    select distinct user_id,last_value(value) over (partition by user_id) last_val
    from comments
    ;
```

The query returns the last value of each user

output:

```
user_id, last_val
'Mark', 'comment4'
'Tim', 'comment4'
```

Answer (score -1):

Because there is no such function called as last() in mysql..

Try to use group, order by clause in mysql

Answer (score -1):

The best way I found how to handle this:

```
SELECT user_id, json_unquote(json_extract(json_objectagg('value',  value), '$.value'))
FROM my_table
GROUP BY user_id
```