# mysql count last_column_data not working

Tags: mysql

I have a table name: serial

```
ID            Name             Date
----          --------         -----------           
1             George           2013-07-24
2             John             2013-07-24
3             Thomas           2013-07-25
4             James            2013-07-31
5             Andrew           2013-07-20
6             Martin           2013-07-24
7             William          2013-07-21
8             Zachary          2013-07-25
9             Millard          2013-07-31
10            Chester          2013-07-24
```

Now I need count of the last value of column Date dynamically, here the last value of column Date is 2013-07-24, so the count is 4. But if some data insert into ID#11 with the Date value 2013-07-31,then the count will be 3.
I have made a function to do this:

```
function countdate(){   
    $SQL = "SELECT count( `ID` ) as countdate FROM serial WHERE `Date` = 'LAST(Date)'"; 
    $result = mysql_query($SQL);    
    $cd= mysql_fetch_array($result);
    return $cd['countdate'];
}
```

But it is not working. But if I put directly '2013-07-24' instead of 'LAST(Date)' into the function, it gives the result. I think 'LAST(Date)' is not working here dynamically. 
What is the mistake here or any other way......By the way, I am not very expert coder, and it's my first question, so...

Here MAX(value) might not work as different dates are insert into here. MAX(value) may work here if we consider the column 'ID'. But the values of the column 'Date' not incremental here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can i use aggregation function (LAST) in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495913/can-i-use-aggregation-function-last-in-mysql)

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so (you haven't), provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so (again, you haven't), provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try with a sub query:

`` SELECT COUNT(*) countdate FROM serial WHERE `Date` = (SELECT `Date` FROM serial order by ID desc limit 1) ``