# SELECT LAST(CustomerName) AS LastCustomer FROM Customers;

Tags: mysql

I am beginner to mysql, while I practice **syntax of LAST()** i.e 
`SELECT LAST(CustomerName) AS LastCustomer FROM CUSTOMERS;` 
**I am getting an error.**

> Error : ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for
>   the right syntax to use near '(CustomerName) AS LastCustomer FROM
>   CUSTOMERS' at line 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can i use aggregation function (LAST) in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495913/can-i-use-aggregation-function-last-in-mysql)

Comment: `LAST()` is not supported in mySQL.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve in that `LAST(CustomerName)`

Comment: I am trying for last name in column "CustomerName" of table "CUSTOMERS.

Comment: Define what you mean by "last name".  The last one inserted--not possible, unless you timestamped each.  In that case, `ORDER BY timestamp DESC`.

Comment: Clarify your question, or expect it to be "closed".

Answer (score 2):

the thing is there is nothing on mysql like **LAST()** function. You can see the comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495913/can-i-use-aggregation-function-last-in-mysql?answertab=active#tab-top) where it is said.

You can find the list of mysql functions visiting [mysql aggregated functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html)

It is better to use simple query like the following -

```
SELECT CustomerName as LastCustomer ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Hope it helps...:)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS ORDER BY customer_id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: `order by` missing. and also `max(ID_FIELD)` is better

Comment: i don't know his id field therefor i wrote your_auto_increment_field

Answer (score 0):

Last() is not supported in Mysql so try 
SELECT TOP 1 CustomerName FROM Customers ORDER BY CustomerID DESC;

Comment: Top is not a MYSQL function.